# Linux process misbehaving (MQTT) if redirecting output to file

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I have developed Linux module that uses MQTT communication over TCP.
There was no issue with the functionality until i made a script to auto start the module and redirect the stdout and stderr to a file.

After redirecting, all other communications work perfectly but the MQTT communication has issues. if i send a message every 1 sec they arrive suddenly in a bunch after some 30+ seconds.

This odd behaviour only happens if i use the redirecting of output to file.

My startup script

```
/bin/su -c "/usr/local/bin/TestApp 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime(\"%F %T TestApp:\"), \$0; fflush(); }' | tee -a /home/TestApp.txt &" - root
```

Then i tried this (but same issue)

```
/bin/su -c "/usr/local/bin/TestApp 2>&1 | tee -a /home/TestApp.txt &" - root
```

SO I tried this (and again same issue)

```
/usr/local/bin/TestApp 2>&1 | tee -a /home/TestApp.txt &
```

This too doesnt work

```
/usr/local/bin/TestApp 2>&1 > /home/TestApp.txt &
```

The only thing that is working without any issues is

```
/usr/local/bin/TestApp 2>&1
```

What is the reason that the MQTT communication misbehaves because of redirection of output ?

please help.

Edit: MQTT code added:

**MQTT Init function:**

```
int mqttInit(void) {
MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
int rc;

MQTTAsync_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE,NULL);

MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, NULL);

conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 300;//20;
conn_opts.cleansession = true;
conn_opts.onSuccess = onConnect;
conn_opts.onFailure = onConnectFailure;
conn_opts.context = client;
conn_opts.automaticReconnect = true;

if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    rc= EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return rc;
}
```

**Function that gets triggerd when data is received:**

```
int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen,MQTTAsync_message *message) {
int i;
char* payloadptr;
char temp[20];
int rc;

printf("===================\n MQTT msgarrvd: \n topic: %s \n paylength=%d \n payload=", topicName, message->payloadlen);

for (i = 0; i < message->payloadlen; i++) {
    msgarrvd_Buff[i] = *payloadptr++;
    printf("%02X", msgarrvd_Buff[i]);
}

printf("\n===================\n");
printf("Message arrived \r\n");
```

}

Comment: Are the lines sent by TestApp terminated by LF ('\n')? Line buffering can produce such delays when lines are not terminated by LF.

Comment: The commands that are sent over MQTT are XML or HEX or strings they will not have any LF. however every time a command/response is received i print them on the console with LF. This issue is not with the output file not getting the data reflected, rather the MQTT messages dont arrive in the thread ('msgarrvd' from paho library)

Comment: Add the code for your app, without it we have no way of knowing what you are doing.

Comment: updated OP with MQTT functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so appears that what @user803422 mentioned in the comment is the solution.

after banging my head for so long, i added the below line on code in the main file and now its working as expected

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL );
```